# YouTube API Insight CSV

Tags: php, youtube-api, gdata-api

I want to retrieve and then download the YouTube Insight CSVs for my videos.
Following the instructions in this question: [PHP Youtube API - Getting Insight Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5299110/php-youtube-api-getting-insight-data),
I wrote the following code:

```
$httpClient = Zend_Gdata_AuthSub::getHttpClient($sessionToken);
$yt=new Zend_Gdata_YouTube($httpClient,$clientName,$applicationName,$developerKey);
$yt->setMajorProtocolVersion(2);
$url='http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/my_user_name/uploads';

$feed=$yt->getVideoFeed($url);
```

But when I iterate through the links i get in the feed (using ->getLink('')), I see no link for the CSV (That is, a link with `'rel=http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#insight.views'`
I'm authenticated and I'm the owner of the videos.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why is no one answering? Is this a bad question?